# php: dynamic preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The code below is not a functioning method it's just written to help you understand what I'm trying to do.

```
// $i = occurrence to replace
// $r = content to replace

private function inject($i, $r) {
      // regex matches anything in the format {value|:value}
      $output = preg_replace('/\{(.*?)\|\:(.*?)\}/', '$r', $this->source);
      $output[$i]
}
```

How do I find the $i occurrence in $output; and replace it with $r;?

Note: All I want to do is use $i (which is a number) to find the occurrence of that nmber in a preg_replace; For exmaple:  I might want to replace the second occurrence of the preg_replace pattern with the variable $r

Comment: Does $i contain a regex or a string you want to find?

Comment: what's in $i? the whole pattern? Needs some more details.

Comment: The occurrence number of the matched item.  $i for example could be 1 then, regex needs to find the 1 occurence and replace it with $r;

Comment: @willm1 the number of the string occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only accomplish such an occurence counting with a callback:

```
private function inject($i, $r) {
      $this->i = $i;
      $this->r = $r;

      // regex matches anything in the format {value|:value}
      $output = preg_replace_callback('/\{(.*?)\|\:(.*?)\}/',
                array($this, "inject_cb"), $this->source);
}

function inject_cb($match) {
    if ($this->i --) {
        return $match[0];
    }
    else {
        return $this->r;
    }
}
```

It leaves the first `$i` matches as is, and uses the tempoary `$this->r` once when the countdown is matched. Could be done with a closure to avoid `->$i` and `->$r` however.

Comment: Can't seem to get this working?  I'm sure it is probably an error on my part.

Comment: It needs to do something with $output still. An alternative option for this task would be `preg_split` with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` maybe (but more fiddly).

Comment: I think these two functions need to be wrapped inside a class (as methods) for this to work.